# why when I use " from module import * " and I want want to see functions of the module by help (module) it is not working?

Tags: python-3.x

why should I use just `import module` to see the functions in it?

By help (module )
but it is not woking with   `from module import *`
is there any way to see the functions of it by `from module import *`

Comment: Hello, Potentially you need to add some more details like a specific example/library where you have this problem. Look at the [MCVE ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide for help on how to format the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `from module import *` - only the exported symbols from `module` are added to your module. The name `module` itself is not imported. Since `help` merely looks at documentation of imported symbols, that's why your `help(module)` is not working.

```
>>> from os import *
>>> help(os)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
>>>
```

What you can do is this:

```
>>> import os
>>> help(os)

>>> 
>>> from os import path
>>>
```